strange Java flush() bug
I log a series of letters to System.err.println as I traverse a tree. Afterward, I do the following:
System.err.flush();
System.out.println("After flush");

but when I run the program (no threads, single-threaded), the output is sometimes interleaved and sometimes not:
A
B
B
C
C
After flush
D
D

A
B
B
C
C
D
D
After flush

A
B
B
C
C
D
After flush
D

the above 3 snippets are from 3 consecutive runs. I'm using Java SE 8 due to some requirements.

Not Java-specific at all. There's no well-defined ordering between writes to different file descriptors at the OS-level; this is true no matter what programming language you use.
